# PHP - server side validation of video?

Tags: php, validation, video

I know that you can use `getimagesize()` on pictures to check the mime type, and then check if it matches a whitelist. Is there something similar for videos?

I would like my user to be able to upload a picture and a video clip to my server. My first though was to check the extension of the file but this seems limited.

Comment: Did you have a look at [`mime_content_type`](http://php.net/mime_content_type)

Comment: @secelite no, I'll check that out. Is that universal? If so I would try to use that over getimagesize()

Answer (score 1):

Checkout [getID3](http://getid3.sourceforge.net/), it supports video formats.